# How to find proportions: x as a proportion of y.

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

I have two questions, firstly, what is 21 as a proportion of 510 (expressed as a decimal), and secondly, what is 66 as a proportion of 510 (expressed as a decimal)?

Comment: What are your own tought on the subject?

Answer (score 2):

$(1)$ Simplify/divide out $\dfrac {21}{510}$

$(2)$ Simplify/divide out $\dfrac{66}{510}$.

Comment: Clean and concise! +1